# How can I make outbound calls with a Twilio number?

Tags: iphone, twilio, telephony, twilio-twiml

I have registered a phone number within twilio to use as "my" phone number.

I set up a simple twiml bin do handle call forwarding to whatever phone SIM/handset I am using right now.  So people call my (twilio) number and it forwards to my phone.

However, if I make an outbound call from my phone, of course the callerID is from my SIM, not my twilio number.  This confuses people and is inconvenient.

What is the best (easiest) way for me to place calls, using my current phone/SIM/number, but have the call come from my twilio number ?

(I am currently using an iphone, FWIW)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a few options here. You can implement the [Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios) into an iPhone app that you can then use to make calls from. There are quickstarts and example applications available here: https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift#quickstart

Alternatively, you could update your incoming webhook to point at some code that works out if it is your number dialling or not. If it is not, then carry on with the current forwarding behaviour. If it is your number, then ask what number you want to dial and take the digits using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather), then use a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) to make the outbound call.

You could also install a SIP phone app to your device and set up [SIP registration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/sip-registration). You would then need to [set up some TwiML to make outgoing calls from the SIP endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/sip-registration#sip-out).

Just some ideas there. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. Item 1 is beyond my capabilities, so looking at item 2 - you're saying every number I dial, I dial my own number and type in extra digits after twilio answers, which will then forward to that second number ?  I thought of that but I think it makes address book / contacts impossible, right ?

Comment: Looking on to your third example, that is probably the most user friendly - do you have an iOS SIP dialer that you recommend ?  Any issues with call quality or features that I will miss or is it basically equivalent to the native dialer ?  Thank you.

Comment: I've used a free app called Linphone, which does a decent job. I believe Bria is a good paid alternative. Using Linphone is like using a dialer and it gets access to contacts too, I'm sure that's the same for most SIP phone apps, so this might be the solution for you.

Comment: OK, I think the solution is as follows ... inbound calls are "normal" - my twilio number has a simple forward twiml bin that sends all calls to whatever my current SIM card is.  I answer these calls just like a normal phone.  But outbound calls are initiated with the SIP dialer app (whichever one I choose) - which means I will not use the normal iphone dialer, but will always place my calls with the SIP dialer.   Thanks!

Comment: I am stuck, conceptually, on the last detail ... you said  "set up some TwiML to make outgoing calls from the SIP endpoint" ... however, that phone number already has a twiml bin in place for the call forwarding to my current mobile phone.  So if I use up the "voice call" slot with the twiml bin that forwards incoming calls to me, where to I put the twiml bin that tells outgoing calls to go through my SIP endpoint ?  Is there a place to configure a twiml bin in a SIP trunk ?  I did not see one ...

Comment: There's a voice configuration section when you [edit your SIP domain](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/sip/endpoints). That allows you to set a webhook, which you can set to the URL of a TwiML Bin.

Comment: Thank you for your continued advice and help.  May I ask you - is there a SMS equivalent to this ?  That is, if I have a SMS forwarder that gets SMS to my twilio number to my current mobile phone, if I reply, they get a reply from my SIM card number ... is there a way for my reply to have my Twilio number as the FROM ?   Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly. Firstly, if you respond to your SMS forwarder, it will just forward that message back to you. You could build a webhook that checks for your number, and if it is, do something different with the SMS, for example, send it on to the last number that sent it a message. This could be a bit awkward though and there is a potential race condition. Probably best is to create or use some sort of inbox to receive and send Twilio SMS messages from. I wrote a [simple one here](https://github.com/philnash/sms-messages-app) or you could use something like [Front](https://frontapp.com/).

Comment: How would I integrate the iOS Quick Start example with these API https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls, there are example for https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/php,

Comment: @SadmanSamee I am not sure what you mean there and I don't think the comments of an answer are the best place to discuss. Could you formulate this as a question, tagged Twilio, with any code that you have tried and errors you are seeing and I'll try to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Now there is a Twilio mobile app for iOS and Android called TwiConnect https://twiconnect.com

You can login through your Twilio Account SID, choose one of your Twilio Voice or SMS numbers as a default one, then you will be able to make outgoing calls or send/receive SMS messages usi

Comment: I think I used it before but now it's called TALKYTO and requires a hefty monthly subscription fee on top of the Twilio usage fees of course (at least hefty for occasional usage)